# Extracting Data from Multiple PDFs'

Tags: python, parsing, pdf

I am trying to extract data from PDF document and have regarding that - I was able to get the code working for one single PDF. However, is there a way I can point the code to a folder with multiple PDF's and get the extract out in CSV? I am a complete beginner in Python, so any help will be appreciated. Below is the current code that I have.

```
import pdfplumber
import pandas as pd


file = 'Test Slip.pdf'

lines = []

with pdfplumber.open(file) as pdf:
pages = pdf.pages
for page in pdf.pages:
    text = page.extract_text()
    for line in text.split('\n'):
        lines.append(line)
        print(line)

df = pd.DataFrame(lines)

df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible option would be to use `os.listdir` and only read files that end in `.pdf`:

```
import os
folder_with_pdfs = '/path/to/folder'
for pdf_file in os.listdir(folder_with_pdfs):
    if pdf_file.endswith('.pdf'):
        pdf_file_path = os.path.join(folder_with_pdfs, pdf_file)
        # do pdf reading with opening pdf_file_path
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you aim to write lines to a dataframe as rows but this should be what you need:

```
import pdfplumber
import pandas as pd
import os

def extract_pdf(pdf_path):
    linesOfFile = []
    with pdfplumber.open(pdf_path) as pdf:
        for pdf_page in pdf.pages:
            single_page_text = pdf_page.extract_text()
            for linesOfFile in single_page_text.split('\n'):
                linesOfFile.append(line)
                #print(linesOfFile)
    return linesOfFile


folder_with_pdfs = 'folder_path'
linesOfFiles = []
for pdf_file in os.listdir(folder_with_pdfs):
    if pdf_file.endswith('.pdf'):
        pdf_file_path = os.path.join(folder_with_pdfs, pdf_file)
        linesOfFile = extract_pdf(pdf_file_path)
        linesOfFiles.append(linesOfFile)
        
df = pd.DataFrame(linesOfFiles)
df.to_csv('test.csv')
```